# How can I get Movable Type 5 experimental package?

Tags: 10.04, package-management, ppa, apt

I'd like to install the movabletype-opensource package for version 5.0  I currently have Ubuntu 10.04 installed.  How do I install the experimental package?  Do I need to add a site to my apt sources?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Currently, version 4.3.3-1 is in the lucid/10.04 repositories (4.3.4-1 is in the maverick/10.10 and natty/11.04 repositories). Debian does not have any 5.0 versions, and a quick PPA search on Launchpad did not turn anything up either.

You can download the latest version from the [movabletype.org](http://www.movabletype.org/) [download page](http://www.movabletype.org/download.html). The site also contains an [installation guide](http://www.movabletype.org/documentation/installation/index.html).

If you would prefer to install movabletype-opensource from an actual deb package, you might be interested in this [bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=582724) on the Debian BTS reporting that 5.0 is available upstream and requesting and updated package or this [Request For Help Bug](http://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=572484).

Comment: Yep.  Looks like the only solution is outside apt.  Thanks for searching!